# Is there any way to determine if audio is being sent over HDMI versus the service not running?

Tags: linux-mint, pulseaudio

Mint 20 HTPC -> HDMI (on mobo) -> receiver -> TV.

I have this situation where sometimes there is no audio coming out of the receiver. I have tried restarting the service and that doesn't seem to fix it. Is there any way that I can determine if the pulse audio service is sending audio or not? In ssh / bash.